# Merge two events, detect which is raised

Tags: events, f#

I have two buttons, and I want to merge their click events, and then wait for either of them to be clicked (using async), and then depending on which button got pressed, I want to perform different actions.

I have been trying to use `Async.AwaitObservable` with `Observable.merge` but I can't get it to work (does it even exist?) and I have been trying to use `Observable.map` to assign returnvalues to the event, but I cant get anything to work.

I want to use a match expression to perform different actions based on what button I click.

Storytime:
This is to prevent my program from having mutables.
My program is a drawing program using windows forms and f#.
It should be able to draw two diffrent shapes and I dont want to keep track of which "tool" I'm using by using mutables, so instead I want to await the event and determine from there.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no `Async.AwaitObservable` method (at least on my system), using `Async.AwaitEvent` and the equivalent functions of the `Event` module instead of `Observable` should work.

```
type WhichButton = B0Clicked | B1Clicked

let clicks =
    (   b0.Click |> Event.map (fun _ -> B0Clicked) ,
        b1.Click |> Event.map (fun _ -> B1Clicked) )
    ||> Event.merge 

let waitForClicks() = async{
    while true do
        let! clicked = Async.AwaitEvent clicks
        match clicked with
        | B0Clicked -> printfn "Button 0"
        | B1Clicked -> printfn "Button 1" }
```